# Keep track of a timer even when the user isn't on the page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, timer

At the moment, I have a simple signup and login PHP system going,
I want to achieve a little timer which the user can set up for their personal use, I was wondering if they could type in something like 12 hours and then a timer would count down until that timer ran out and they could start it again, I was thinking the timer could keep going even when they don't have the page loaded, so I was thinking it needed to be stored in a mySQL database, I am just having great difficulty with this and I hope I'm not asking for too much.

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: PHP only executes when a request is made. But you can simulate the fact that it was still running by doing this: the user sets a timer for 12 hours, ok, what time will it be in 12 hours ? Save that. And next time the user comes back, display the time remaining to this time.

Comment: you could also do this with local storage and simulate the countdown in the same way as described by @blex. Or just set the activation time (and store in either localStorage or the Db) and then on page load grab the activation time and also the current time - do the maths to subtract the time lapsed between the activation and current times and simulate the countdown. Note that you CANNOT use session storage for this.

Comment: Say a user sets up a timer for 12 hours from now. The user then logs off, shuts down their computer and goes to sleep. What would happen after 12 hours?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I'm working on calculating the end time from the hours they put in and then I hope I will get it to work    @apokryfos and at the end of the timer it will trigger some events like an email notification and a button activates allowing them to start it over again.

Comment: @Josh You won't be able to send an email at a particular time with PHP, unless a request is made. You'll need to use another technology, to either do that, or to launch a _job_ every X minutes (the _job_ being a script that checks whether some timers have come to an end, and an email needs to be sent)

Comment: @blex any suggestions? I'm keen to learn if it is a different language.

Comment: I like NodeJS, it's Javascript that runs on the server, and it runs all the time (it can do things even when no one is requesting anything, unlike PHP). And you'll find plenty of documentation and tutorials. Some keywords: _nodejs_, _express_ (library to help you setup a server), _mongodb_ (database system that you can use instead of MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

The following will probably work but requires a system which has crontab (could work in windows with a task scheduler but the syntax would be different).

Create a table:

```
UserTimers
----------
user_id | timer_id | trigger_time
```

When a user creates a timer add it to this table.

Create an executable PHP script (say it's stored at `/etc/cronmgr`)

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
$rows = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM UserTimers WHERE trigger_time <= NOW()"); // Timer should have been triggered by now
//Get all rows and do whatever you need to do with them
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM UserTimers WHERE trigger_time <= NOW()");
```

Add the following line in your crontab:

```
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronmgr
```

This will run your cronmgr script every 2 minutes (adjust if you think there's going to be too much server load).

However a user's timer may be off by X minutes (where X is the interval, i.e. 2 in this example) so if a user asks for a timer of 1 minute, that won't work as well.